# Does Dash have a multi page app design such that all data for all pages must be loaded at startup?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have been working on a multi page app in dash for weeks now.  And, just at the conclusion of it being ready to demo for my company, it seems a glaring data design issue has arisen.

Is it the case that in a multi-page app, dash can only startup by loading all data for all pages at startup and not load the data for each page when and if it is accessed by a user?

This would be a stunning design flaw if true, but everything I have found so far indicates that all callbacks fire and all data is loaded for all pages at startup.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The only suggestion I have would be to create separate apps with separate layouts, but add buttons or links to the other 'pages'. Each separate 'page' would be its own hosted app. Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: You can pass `prevent_initial_callbacks=True` as a parameter to the app: `Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)` to have it so all callbacks are not run immediately. Or you can disable it per callback using `prevent_initial_call=True` as a parameter to a callback.